# При создании нескольких классов не могу использовать переменные

Tags: c#, классы, переменные

При создании нескольких классов не могу использовать переменные

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace ZenosMiner
{
    class First
    {
    string Simple;
    Simple = "Не могу использовать переменную";
    }
    class Second
    {
    string Simple;
    Simple = "Не могу использовать переменную";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class First
{
  public string Simple = "Mогу инициализировать переменную";

  public void SomeMethod()
  {
    Simple = "Mогу присвоить значение переменной";
  }

  public string SomeOtherMethod()
  {
    return Simple; // Mогу использовать переменную
  }

  // Simple = "Не могу поместить прямо в тело класса";
}
```